# Simulate D Flip-Flop

Tags: code-golf, string, bitwise, electrical-engineering

## Objective

Simulate an edge-triggered [D Flip-Flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop).

## What is D Flip-Flop?

A D flip-flop is an electronic digital device that outputs an inputted **data** (abbr. D) with synchronization to a **clock** (abbr. CLK). Usually CLK is a uniform pulse, but in this challenge, CLK may be not uniform.

## Input

A bitstring with length \$n\$ will be given as CLK and another bitstring with length \$n-1\$ will be given as D. A bit represents the state of an input during a unit time (tick). CLK leads D by half a tick.

## Output

The output (abbr. Q) is a bitstring with same length and starting timepoint as D. If CLK doesn't start with `01`, the starting bit of Q is implementation-defined. Q is updated upon a rising moment of CLK to the bit of D at the time. On the other times, Q retains its state.

## Examples

The red line indicates a rising moment of CLK.

- Example 1:

[image: D flip-flop]

- Example 2:

[image: D flip-flop 2]

## Rules

- If CLK isn't a tick longer than D, the entire challenge falls into *don't care* situation.
- Though defined as bitstrings, the actual elements of CLK, D, and Q doesn't matter. In this case, if a string is not binary (that is, contains a third character), the entire challenge falls into *don't care* situation.

Comment: I haven't heard of most of these terms so I don't know what the challenge is asking for without following the link to the Wikipedia page. Please add the the relevant information to the challenge body itself.

Comment: @xnor the Output section actually specifies the output here

Comment: Thanks. If possible, a test case where people can copy and paste would be much appreciated.

Comment: With the well-illustrated examples, I think I now understand what the output section is asking for. Thinking of the bit strings as time series, whenever the CLK bit changes from 0 to 1, the output bit Q is set to the current value of the bit D. In all other cases, Q stays unchanged from what it was last.

Comment: `The starting bit of Q is implementation-defined.` Only if CLK does not start with `01`? Or does the starting bit *never* matter?

Comment: @Jitse Only if CLK doesn't start with `01`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is 11100000111111111111111000000000011 a valid output for Example 1 (since CLK doesn't start with `01`)?

Comment: @GalenIvanov Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εINTS+èÆi©ë®Θ
```

First input is \$D\$, second input is \$CLK\$.
Output \$Q\$ as a list of 0s and 1s.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZPv5Bg7cMrDrdlHlp5ePWhdedm/P9vaACGQGBgACagFEgUzDI05AILQmUMYYoh@gwgwNAQAA) or [verify both test cases (and pretty-print)](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/kpuTs422loGTvaRvKpeRipaAAZnMZahxaGfP/3NYIv5Bg7cMrDrdlHlp5ePWhdedm/K@t9VIKhCjU4Tq0zf6/ARAYggkQAJNgEUOIKFiCC8KFyEEUQCiwIog2LkOYHoggHBpAdBqA1HMZQm1BmAW1FSoEZPzX1c3L181JrKoEAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε            # Map over the (implicit) input-list D:
  N          #  Push the current map-index
   TS        #  Push 10 as digit-list: [1,0]
     +       #  Add them to the index: [index+1, index]
 I    è      #  Index both of them into the second input CLK
       Æi    #  If they are [1,0]:
         ©   #   Store the current map-value in variable `®` (without popping)
        ë    #  Else:
         ®   #   Push variable `®`
          Θ  #   And check whether it is exactly 1 (1 if truthy, 0 if falsey)
             #   (which is necessary, because `®` is -1 by default)
             # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

```
;@(<@({.\);.1~1,2</\}.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/PCsIwDMbvfYqgwlqYMfG4PzAUPIkHr5un6RAvPsDYXr3WybZ0UykpIb8vyZeHXWBQQRpBACEQRC7WCPvz8WDjTCeZrrEwMXLL4TbZFA0aa9Rph@CoXibZqkYfdzCP4v80n1Nu8PIDO/RWDFiPJSOUuVJliu6Cz2OR9Y9E1mvY044d6uqGgSeRzXIMeXWaKNyvbuX9CSVULVwVdDZ5tlx2zoM8D9TvG1z6R37zypNenhCSLu0L)

`CLK` is the left argument; `D` is the right one. When `CLK` doesn't start with `01`, the starting bits are the same as the first bit of `D`.

```
                       ;.1  - cut 
                          ] - the right argument (D)
   (          )             - where
         2 /\               - the previous element 
             [              - of the left argument (CLK)
          <                 - is smaller than the next one 
       }.                   - drop
      1                     - the first item
    1,                      - prepend with 1 (for cutting)
               (     )      - for each cut group
                   $        - make a list   
                #           - of the same length as the group
                    {.      - with elements same as the first one  
                 <@         - and box the list
  ;                         - unbox the sublists and flatten them
[:                          - function composition
```

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>27</s>  23bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{,/&\'|\'(0,&1_>':x)_y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWkdfLUa9JkZdw0BHzTDeTt2qQjO@svZ/WrShgqGCARwboLANsWCEuCGcBopZQwUQwgZIPAMUWYQ2QzQZg1gF/dSKxNyCnFQFo/8A)

Comment: [J, 23 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY/PCsIwDMbvfYqgwlqYMfG4PzAUPIkHr5un6RAvPsDYXr3WybZ0UykpIb8vyZeHXWBQQRpBACEQRC7WCPvz8WDjTCeZrrEwMXLL4TbZFA0aa9Rph@CoXibZqkYfdzCP4v80n1Nu8PIDO/RWDFiPJSOUuVJliu6Cz2OR9Y9E1mvY044d6uqGgSeRzXIMeXWaKNyvbuX9CSVULVwVdDZ5tlx2zoM8D9TvG1z6R37zypNenhCSLu0L).

Comment: @Bubbler Great, thanks!

Comment: `{(#x)#*x}'` -> `&\'|\'`

Comment: @ngn Thank you, that's very interesting!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 16 bytes

```apl
∊⊣⊣\¨⍤⊂⍨1,1↓2</⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FH16OuxUAUc2jFo94lj7qaHvWuMNQxfNQ22chG/1HXov9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/MkTJoRXqBkBgCCZAAEyCRQwhomAJda4UmHoFdYgURB1EMYQCa4AYoc5VilBvADcGBRgYGCCZH4pkPlSOgPrOhSkKaQrJXLrEAC6Efw1hXoO4Fw4NIJ4yANmE6l9owCC8DA0oqBCQgeZfmIOR1cN9AGKh@5cY9VD/AgA)

A dyadic tacit function whose right arg is CLK and left arg is D. Accepts both as Boolean vectors. The starting bit of Q follows that of D.

#### How it works

```apl
∊⊣⊣\¨⍤⊂⍨1,1↓2</⊢  ⍝ Input: left←D, right←CLK
            2</⊢  ⍝ Detect rising edges of CLK
        1,1↓      ⍝ Treat the very first tick as a rising edge
 ⊣    ⊂⍨          ⍝ Partition D into regions where
                  ⍝   each rising edge marks the start of each region
  ⊣\¨⍤            ⍝ On each region, overwrite all elements with the first one
∊                 ⍝ Enlist; form a simple vector
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>40</s>  39 bytes

Takes input as `(clock)(data)`, where *clock* and *data* are arrays of binary digits.

```javascript
C=>D=>D.map(c=>C[i]<C[++i]?p=c:p,i=p=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BDoMgEEX3nMKdECmZ2TYdu6C3MC4M1QZjgdSm16dNjVW0mSGZwP@fN33zakbzsOF5cP7axo6ipvLyaXVvAjdU6srWJ10Vha3PgcwxSEuBQETj3eiHVg3@xjvOsqwCORXKZZoLVtOswUT7c9RMfOMwkS3mdQwk97BRTGGq99bxPBeCsT007lDWOfsDCRHMvy/Q6c7/0HFjxs0LJNDxDQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 56 bytes

The space before `:=` is mandatory, otherwise the colon would be part of the undefined identifier.

Argh. Just 1 byte away from Java!

```
method(c,d,q :=0;d map(i,x,q=if(c at(i)<c at(i+1),x,q)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY89DsIwDIX3nMJjLDzYK9CbsFQNFUb9hQzcvrSqSuqUWFEs@@Xzs/ZT3egA5wJuU3uPjz74igKNc4UvAdpy8EofGgutfQVl9IrX9T0JLg1EXBHewXwafUfPtIZQyrbgXbZpxGh/P5ASUow0AfYoNnXOFAvQITx77WB4aRebzrncuRz87EHHy8YSb@Otc7v8P/@SASTrcO58@gI)

## Explanation

```
method(c, d,                // Take 2 operands, c and d
    q := 0                  // Set the flip flop to 0
    d map (i, x,            // Map every item in d
                            // With the index i and the
                            // current item x
        q = \               // Set the current flip-flop as:
            if(c at(i)      // If the clock at the same index
            < c at(i + 1),  // Is less than the clock at the next index?
                            // I.e. the clock goes from 0 to 1
                x,          // Set the flip-flop as the current item x
                q           // Otherwise, make an identity function.
            )               // The assigned operand result is automatically
    )                       // returned to the map loop, so no
)                           // explicit reference of the flip-flop in the map.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda C,D,x=0:[x:=[x,d][a<b]for d,a,b in zip(D,C,C[1:])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY89b8MgEIZ3fsXJE0g0AnWprDLZ6VrFq@sB17ZC69iIUNVp1d/u8uE47ZQc0gF377086JPdj8P9gzZzJ17mXh7qRkJGczoJlpZTKsqJNlUpH@uqGw00VNIa1ABfSuOcZjQreVqRav7cq74FniKw5uQyZKJXR4sPUmM1WKoG/WEx2RytcZOEECfJr0t21yVLDUE7vbbawvb5aWvMaDxEbVr5jqAQHXZ/chptnA1Oks3bqIZg66xoQQiFLim/CyF2P1VCZuaCh@Qj5FDhsRoaCOI9NqMibkEV5xCwdeBfMHZpoLtbAvHz@9F/XSxCMG/qoBbkC9fyhaXkDh7qTPFXtGL5021Qvw)

**Input**: 2 lists of 0s and 1s, the first list `C` represents the clock line, and the second list `D` represents the data line.
**Output**: The list `Q` representing the state of the flip-flop through time.

#### Explanation

- `for d,a,b in zip(D,C,C[1:])` iterates over the lines, where `d` is the current data bit, `a` is the previous clock bit, and `b` is the current clock bit
- `x` stores the previous state of the flip-flop
- `x:=[x,d][a<b]` updates the state of the flip-flop: if `a<b` is `1` (edge-rise moment), then the state is updated to the current data bit `d`. Otherwise, the state remains the same as previous state.

Comment: Why is there "(pre-release)" behind "Python 3.8"? Python 3.8 was released months ago.

Comment: @Mast true, I just copied the title from TIO and didn't think much about it

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 55 bytes

```java
C->D->{int i=0,p=0;for(int c:D)D[i]=C[i]<C[++i]?p=c:p;}
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201573/52210), so make sure to upvote him!!

Input as two integer-arrays. Stores the result (\$Q\$) in input \$D\$ instead of returning a new list to save bytes.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVJRa4MwEH7vrzjyFLEGC3sYtjqGspdtsNHH4kOW2i2d1aBnQUp/u4tJunbQsgjJeffdd98X3fI9D7br70GUvG3hlcvqMAFokaMUsNVV1qEs2aarBMq6Yk8uWMgKV/n0GiStq7bbFY2FJAlsIB7SIMmC5KBTIONwquJwvqkbOr6LKPOylczjVG@LdOX7Mn9QsYjU/DjMJ1qO6j5KLcep2tdyDTutlC6xkdXnKgfujaoBsGiRklCvmdnGZXaTmdmsKZApEJuxZYuxh8HZTuLNL4hnJw6L@H1CSxOOzYbYDT5zOyEupQNLfJycL9vYMnOsLUhfnqfg4swZXPYtFjtWd8iULmBZUaJxERBfH07sNVAW6QLxMwcxnwZ4BjFkTHzxpqUe23FFRZCI4O7eY1g/Ng3vqWvYMK5U2VM95R@8x7gQhULKT8OcB9UUiP3bqEiPJcQRu78AIdJ6vD8oPwa8bendWrpouO3f3fZx@AE)

**Explanation:**

```java
C->D->{                  // Method with two integer-arrays as parameter and no return-type
  int i=0,               //  Index-integer, starting at 0
      p=0;               //  Previous integer, starting at 0
  for(int c:D)           //  Loop over the digits of input D:
    D[i]=                //   Set the `i`'th value of array D to:
         C[i]            //    If the `i`'th value of array C
             <C[++i]?    //    is smaller than the `i+1`'th value of array C
                         //    (thus C[i] == 0 and C[i+1] == 1)
                     p=c //     Use the current digit `c`,
                         //     and also replace `p` with this digit
                    :    //    Else (they're [0,0], [1,0] or [1,1]):
                     p;} //     Use digit `p` instead
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>80</s></sup> 67 bytes

```c
t;f(c,d,n)int*c,*d;{for(t=*c++;n--;d++)*c++=t^*c&&(t^=1)?*d:c[-1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDbaoQwGITv9ynCXiw5iYn0ojRIH2QPEP7oVmiz4qa0VHz1Wnc9JVZKEwyjmZmYD6IzQNs6lWPghltSWEeBU6Pq/FJhl1JgTNkoUoYxcntJ3YnCbofdKZXkmZon2EfyqJq2xHrI6z58jzGmSfnu4EVX@OGRUU1Us3nThcUE1RuEUBdAsD@iFNWC91PyWY1TeGr0yMA7JRo19pq@Vwb@ucXvE8F3sXBMrT2ma/GVXXJsSDyo7jBC7oYSA5N/GqpO53h7sGIYMhxCzBsHuyUKxRRln2UGLjOIxhO0ZLzdkoX//78fEZAQ4609al6xj38NnlzUyMWOmLAl3CQTl2SdXPJfdDOrcQng3dQquqb9hvxVn69t9PED)

Inputs the clock and data as `int` arrays along with the length of the data array.
Returns the output in the clock array starting at one past the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔0ζＦＬη«Ｆ‹§θι§θ⊕ι≔§ηιζζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3NCsIwDD6vTxF2SmFCcva048CDrzC6uhZmh20RUXz2urYTTUi@78uvMqNX67ik1IdgZ4cttR085VFcVg940m6OBo2U8BLNXgoB@zi4ST/w1oGVHfzJwSmvr9pFPaGVm8F@@Dtj6kp@0Zy9dREzfadEREzMXLH6TzGLzDeaeW6URCUKpMN9@QA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔0ζ
```

Initialise `Q`.

```
ＦＬη«
```

Loop over the elements of `D`.

```
Ｆ‹§θι§θ⊕ι
```

Did `CLK` transition from `0` to `1`?

```
≔§ηιζ
```

If so then set `Q` to `D`.

```
ζ
```

Output `Q`.